# Is it possible to use a keyboard as an input in Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I'm new to Arduino, this may be a dumb question but can I use a keyboard to be the main input like a series of buttons but only using a USB/PS2 connection, which will use fewer input pins? I know Arduino Leonardo can emulate a keyboard, but can I use a keyboard as an input to the Arduino? Is it possible? I need a lot of inputs and I'm using an LCD too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. There is a popular library named PS2Keyboard that makes it easy to use a PS2 keyboard as an input for your Uno or other common boards:

https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/PS2Keyboard

You can install it via the Arduino IDE's Library Manager:

1. Sketch > Include Library > Manage Libraries...
2. Wait for the download to complete.
3. In the "Filter your search..." input field type: "PS2Keyboard".
4. Click on the PS2Keyboard item in the search results.
5. Click "Install".
6. Wait for installation to finish.
7. Click "Close".

After following the above steps, the PS2Keyboard library will be installed.

You can find example sketches that demonstrate the usage at **File > Examples > PS2Keyboard**.

Usage and wiring documentation can be found here:

https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_PS2Keyboard.html